# I installed google plugin successfully but i cannot able to view the google icon in my eclipse . let me know what happen

Tags: eclipse, installation, google-plugin-eclipse

Friends tried installing google plugin for eclipse luna by doing the following steps.

1. eclipse -> help -> install new software
2. gave the url -> https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4
3. And it successfully got installed and there was message prompting to restart the eclipse. I restarted

but i cannot able to view the google icon in my eclipse and not any other google plugin options.

I tried restarting the computer also.

I tried with eclipse kepler also with appropriate google plugin

Comment: Having same problem on my MacBook.  I've got a google dropdown in the toolbar on my windows 7 laptop.  Both running Luna with plugin as above.

Comment: @MalcolmMcRoberts : there is a drag and drop option to install eclipse plugin, try that. It will work. It worked for me.

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit?  What am I dragging from where to where?  Are you saying I need to download the package first?  I did notice that though the package install doesn't get an error, no SDK gets installed either.